# Universal Etymology of Words

Tags: etymology

Where could I find examples of words and their etymologies that occur frequently in many different languages?

For example, I know that the English word "Mother" shares a similar etymology with many other languages from civilizations across the globe.

Is there an online resource that provides examples of some (or many!) other words like this.

Comment: @Theta30 That's a great call.  I missed linguistics in the stack exchange list.

Comment: there was even a question about why "mama" is so common in many languages:http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/865/why-do-most-words-for-mother-across-languages-start-with-an-m-and-for-fa

Comment: Probably should have moved it to linguistics before down-voting and closing the question...  Thanks.

Comment: @Norla Please see the comment about automatic downvotes when questions are closed as off topic. It wasn't a user, just the system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.etymonline.com/

This site may help, although it may not be as specific as you are looking for.

Comment: Helpful, definitely, but I was kind of hoping for a paper or such with a list of examples.  Ty though!  +1